# Type of wire to run for mini split AC

Tags: wiring, attic, conduit

I am installing a mini split AC 18k BTU in a bedroom which is across the house from the electrical panel.
The AC requirs a 20 amp breaker (240V) and at 120' run I'm planning to use 10 awg wire. My question is what type of wire. I have 5' from the panel to the attic that'll need a conduit, around 100' of attic run and another 15' of conduit on the other end.
NM/Romex shouldn't be run in conduit but running thhn across 100' of attic seems unwieldy in conduit and not code without conduit. What's the best thing to do here?
Transition wires from thhn to NM in junction boxes back and forth?

Comment: Usually want to limit the amount of connections in a circuit.  You would be adding at least two extra unneeded connection points with changing the wire types.

Comment: AFAIK, you are allowed to run NM-B through conduit so long as it is not outdoors/wet location. You'll just need a wider conduit.. You could also just use BX armored cable.

Comment: Will it go outside? Because the #1 issue here is NM can't.  Is there a good place for a subpanel somewhere? Because you could get 90A AL feeder for barely more $ than the #10, certainly solve any future voltage drop issues (including for 120V circuits fed from that sub), and then power any future circuits at that end of the house.

Comment: DoxyLover The conduit runs are for outside so considered a wet location so NM is out of the question for these parts.

Comment: Harper, while the idea is interesting, I don't have much use for a whole sub panel on that side of the house. The cost of the cable could be similar but the added costs of the actual panel and breaker should also be taken into account.

Comment: What type of "conduit" are you planning to use in the attic?

Comment: Hopefully none. I'd really rather avoid running conduits in the attic. I'm thinking I'll try to run NM in the walls and go to the panel from the back so no conduit is needed at all but I'm not sure whether I can make it work.